# Tailwind CSS does not load in React application

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I checked the documentation several times and several stack overflow answers, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

I tried to change the tailwind file content values several times and also the tail wind base, components and utilities to import. But was unsuccessful as well.

Here's some file snippets:

**_app.tsx**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**global.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .sidebar-icon {
    @apply relative flex items-center justify-center 
      h-12 w-12 mt-2 mb-2 mx-auto
  }
  ...
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
   theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray: {
          900: '#202225',
          ...
        },
      },
      spacing: {
        88: '22rem',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The package.json file

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.5",
    "mobx": "^6.6.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "next": "12.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.16",
    "@types/react": "18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "4.8.3"
  }
}
```

**Project File Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? Can you add your `package.json` file?

Comment: @EdLucas

The css is not working.

package.json file: https://imgur.com/a/GhD6WzF

Comment: Please add your `package.json` file as text in your question. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Also, which CSS is not working? Simple things like `bg-black` or are you referring to your `.sidebar-icon` class?

Comment: *Added it*, but yea nothing worked, so the problem is with tailwind, not just that class in specific

Comment: try to install   postcss and  autoprefixer  and checkout this link https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs